# How to read all of STDOUT produced by system() call into a socket written in C?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, stdout

The following is a code snippet from the server socket that reads a linux command sent by the client, executes it and sends the output back to the client :

```
    while(1){
          char command[200];
          message_read = read(sock, command, sizeof(command));

        if(message_read > 0){
            command[message_read] = '\0';
            dup2(sock, STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup2(sock, STDERR_FILENO);
            system(command);
        }
    }
```

The following is a code snippet of the client that sends a command to the server and receives back the output:

```
          char output[10240];

          send(sock, command, strlen(command), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
          if((message_read = read(sock, output, sizeof(output)))>0){
          output[message_read] = '\0';
          //print the output somewhere
          }
```

While the commands like "ls -al", "pwd", or "whoami" give the output in one go, the client fails to read whole of the output produced by commands like "ping", "ps" or "du". However when I call the above snippet multiple times, it gets me the rest of the output produced by the above commands(in chunks.)

I tried to modify the client function as follows:

```
       send(sock, command, strlen(command), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
       do{
          if((message_read = read(sock, output, sizeof(output))) > 0){
          output[message_read] = '\0';
          //print the output somewhere
          }
        }while(message_read);
```

The above solution hanged the client program. However, after I killed the server, the outputs did show up in the client's window!
Also, this time the output was all scattered and poorly indented.

Q1. What's happening?

Q2. How to solve it?

Comment: Maybe in server part you must flush sock after system(), and in client part is better to read again until some timeout.

Comment: Thanks. I tried flushing after system(). Didn't work!

Comment: Sockets don't have "end of data". Every time you call `read` it reads some data. If there isn't any more data yet then it waits for some data. You can use non-blocking I/O if you want `read` to return straight away when there isn't any more data yet, but that won't solve your problem.

Comment: I agree to what you said @RemyLebeau However, my program is not allowed to create a file and store the stdout data in it. What I can do is pipe the stdout into a string buffer. However, while the size of the output may vary, it would need to get an already allocated string to work with, right? I can play with allocation, but I am afraid that sometimes it may exceed the allocated capacity.

Comment: @ReikiYamya You don't need a file. You can read the stdout into a memory buffer until the end of data is reached, and then send the buffer over the socket. Or, you can read from stdout in fixed blocks until endo f data, sending each block as you go. But either way, you need a way to tell the receiver when the data has finished so it knows when to stop reading from the socket. Either by sending 1 big buffer with a size/terminator, or sending blocks with a 0-length block at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your code is sending and reading strings is not sufficient.

TCP is a byte stream.  There is no 1-to-1 relationship between sends and reads.  As such, the sender MUST either:

1. send the string length before sending the string's data.
2. send a unique terminator after the string data.

And the receiver MUST either:

1. read the length then read the specified amount of data.
2. read until the terminator is reached.

Also, `send()`/`write()` and `recv()`/`read()` can return fewer bytes than requested, so they need to be called in loops (or, in the case of `recv()`, you can use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag).

Try something more like this instead:

```
// common functions ...

bool sendRaw(int sock, void *data, size_t len)
{
    char *ptr = (char*) data;
    while (len > 0) {
        int sent = send(sock, ptr, len, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
        if (sent < 0) return false;
        ptr += sent;
        len -= sent;
    }
    return true;
}

int recvRaw(int sock, void *data, size_t len)
{
    char *ptr = (char*) data;
    while (len > 0) {
        int recvd = recv(sock, ptr, len, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
        if (recvd <= 0) return recvd;
        ptr += recvd;
        len -= recvd;
    }
    return 1;
}

bool sendUInt32(int sock, uint32_t value)
{
    value = htonl(value);
    return sendRaw(sock, &value, sizeof(value));
}

uint32_t recvUInt32(int sock)
{
    uint32_t value;
    if (recvRaw(sock, &value, sizeof(value)) <= 0) return -1;
    return ntohl(value);
}

bool sendString(int sock, const char *str)
{
    uint32_t len = strlen(str);
    if (!sendUInt32(sock, len)) return false;
    return sendRaw(sock, str, len);

    /* alternatively:
    return sendRaw(sock, str, strlen(len) + 1);
    */
}

/*
bool grow(char **str, size_t *cap, size_t stepBy)
{
    size_t newcap = cap + stepBy;
    char *newstr = (char*) realloc(*str, newcap);
    if (!newstr) return false;
    *str = newstr;
    *cap = newcap;
    return true;
}
*/

char* recvString(int sock)
{
    uint32_t len = recvUInt32(sock);
    if (len == -1) return NULL;

    char *str = (char*) malloc(len+1);
    if (!str) return NULL;

    if (recvRaw(sock, str, len) <= 0){
        free(str);
        return NULL;
    }

    str[len] = '\0';
    return str;

    /* alternatively:

    char ch, *str = NULL;
    size_t len = 0, cap = 0;

    do{
        if (recvRaw(sock, &ch, 1) <= 0){
            free(str);
            return NULL;
        }

        if (ch == '\0') break;

        if (len == cap){
            if (!grow(&str, &cap, 256)){
                free(str);
                return NULL;
            }
        }

        str[len++] = ch;
    }
    while (1);

    if (len == cap){
        if (!grow(&str, &cap, 1)){
            free(str);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    str[len] = '\0';
    return str;
    */
}
```

```
// server ...

char *command;

while ((command = recvString(sock)) != NULL){
    // ...
    system(command);
    free(command);

    // read from command's stdout until finished ...

    if (!sendString(sock, output, outputLength)) break;
}
```

```
// client ...

if (sendString(sock, command)){
    char *output = recvString(sock);
    if (output){
        //print the output somewhere
        free(output);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't know the length of the command's response ahead of time, and/or don't want to buffer it all in a single memory buffer, then you can read it in chunks, sending each chunk as you go, eg:

```
// common functions, see above ...

typedef struct _chunk
{
    uint8_t size;
    char data[256];
} chunk;

bool sendChunk(int sock, const chunk *chk)
{
    uint8_t size = chk ? chk->size : 0;
    if (!sendRaw(sock, &size, 1)) return false;
    if (chk) return sendRaw(sock, chk->data, size);
    return true;
}

bool recvChunk(int sock, chunk *chk)
{
    if (recvRaw(sock, &(chk->size), 1) <= 0) return false;
    if (chk->size) return recvRaw(sock, chk->data, chk->size);
    return true;
}
```

```
// server ...

bool sendOutput(int sock)
{
    chunk chk;
    int size;

    do{
        // read from command's stdout ...
        size = read(..., chk.data, sizeof(chk.data));
        if (size <= 0) break;

        chk.size = (uint8_t) size;
        if (!sendChunk(sock, &chk)) return false;
    }
    while(1);
 
    // tell client the data is finished ...
    return sendChunk(sock, NULL);
}

char *command;

while ((command = recvString(sock)) != NULL){
    // ...
    system(command);
    free(command);
    if (!sendOutput(sock)) break;
}
```

```
// client ...

if (sendString(sock, command)){
    chunk chk;
    do{
        if (!recvChunk(sock, &chk)) break;
        if (chk.size == 0) break;
        //print the chk.data somewhere
    }
    while (1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a-million! @RemyLebeau